# Base class for built in objects in ember

Tags: ember.js, base-class, built-in

How to add base class for built in objects (for example controller, router, ...) in ember?

I need to add properties in all controllers and other objects. When I created my controller, I extend from  `MyBaseController`, but built in controller  is extended from `Ember.Controller`. How to force built in controllers extend from `MyBaseController`?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add properties to all instances of a class, you can use `reopen` and `reopenClass` features.
To read more, have a look [this page](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances) from ember guides.

Comment: thanks for your answer, But my point is that when we add a router, by  default Ember  for each router considers a controller,route and template .for example default controller is extended from ember.Controller. my question is Is there a way to determine default class for built in object